# solaris 10 how to find client information?

Tags: nfs, solaris, solaris-10

How can i find which clients are mounting the NFS shares from a solaris 10 NFS server ? i have tried using dfshare on the server which returns nothing.

```
    dfshares -F nfs
```

cheers
osp

Answer (score 3):

Use [`showmount`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26505_01/html/816-5166/showmount-1m.html):

```
/usr/sbin/showmount -a
```

Comment: showmount -a didn't seem to be correct. Ended up checking the share options in dfstab and checking on the clients.

Answer (score -1):

`/usr/sbin/showmount -d` will give you all the mounted directories by remote clients